# Arduino MIDI controller library

Tags: arduino, controller, midi

I am trying to make a MIDI controller with three buttons (play, pause, and rec), a potentiometer and a fader. I am using this library: https://github.com/tttapa/MIDI_controller

I can't manage to make the buttons do what I want (trigger the play button on my daw).

Also when I tested the potentiometers with [Hairless](http://projectgus.github.io/hairless-midiserial/), I got this error:

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5T4c.png)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a communication error.

The autor recommends to [change to the new version](https://github.com/tttapa/Control-Surface). If you want to stay with that version, try tweaking the set speeds on both sides.

The default Hairless baud rate in Arduino is 115,200 symbols/second.

(You could change it in the settings, but I recommend just changing it in Hairless, as I think it is the default.)

```
 MIDI_controller/src/Settings/Settings.h
     Line 10
  #define HAIRLESS_BAUD 115200
```

Comment: I tried this with 9600 and 115200, but the result is the same.

Comment: Use a standard example for testing or try the new lib

Comment: I have updated the library, and used the creators standard example from the readMe, I will post the code [here](https://prnt.sc/rqpokp), but I get the same error.

Comment: Ckeck the baud settings in Serial monitor AND settings.h (Arduino side) AND in win device manager for the used com port AND Hairless app

Comment: The baud rates were different. I set the rate to 115200 in the serial monitor (from9600), settings.h was already to 115200, I set the baud rate os the com port to 115200 in device manager and the hairless app was already set to 115200. So now every freq is matching, but I still get the error. When I open the serial monitor, the output is some weird symbols, is this ok? [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/rqqbn4)

Comment: I have pasted test instructions. Please do them carefully step by step and get back with the result LINK: pastebin.com/GkU6HNCz

Comment: Should I continue to code with this error in hairless and then use flip at the end and hope for the best?

Comment: Use the test code for debugging your hardware its hard to help if you jump around. What is the result of the step by step process. Where did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Your setup does not provide a MIDI input to the DAW. A DAW can read from a MIDI input device but not directly from a serial port.

This setup will work: The Arduino sends MIDI data via serial port to the application "Hairless serial MIDI bridge" and Hairless sends that MIDI data with the correct baudrate to a MIDI input device. The DAW can read the data from the MIDI input device.

You can use http://www.tobias-erichsen.de/software/loopmidi.html as virtual MIDI input.

Have a look at https://piecesofpi.co.uk/arduino-usb-midi-the-easy-way/ for details about the concept.

Another option may be an Arduino with internal USB (Atmega 32U4) without the need for Hairless and the MIDI loopback (I have not tries this).